# Scala Spray identifying exceptions in logging

Tags: scala, spray

I am looking to implement request/response logging in Spray.
Now I have a couple of extra variables I want to include in my log such as user (if resolved), and transactionId, which is just a UUID which will be used when logging various commands and queries, so they can all be linked.

Now if an exception is thrown I go into a custom ExceptionHandler. This only has reference to the RequestContext, not to any additional properties I would like to log against.

Is there any unique indentifier available in the context, or some way to pass in additional values in the ExceptionHandler?

Comment: One way to do this is to define the exception handler on a level where you have all this information available.

Comment: `handleException(handler(user, transactionId))`, etc.

Comment: That is totally working, and unlike logging, nested exception handlers override earlier handlers, so I can do:
provide(UUID.randomUUID) { transactionId =>
  handleException(restExceptionHandler(transactionId) { 
    customAuthDirective() { user =>
       handleException(restExceptionHandler(transactionId, user))

So cheers for that!

Answer (score 0):

From comments above with a clearer example:

```
provide(UUID.randomUUID) { transactionId =>  
  handleException(restExceptionHandler(transactionId) { 
    customAuthDirective() { user => 
      handleException(restExceptionHandler(transactionId, user))
```